# How to keep looping even error happend?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I wrote a PL/pgsql to batch create index on tables

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_index() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN 1..1000
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format(
        ' CREATE INDEX idx_abc_id_' || r::text ||
        ' ON abc_id_' || r::text ||
        ' USING btree
        (key);');
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

it has one problem, if partition abc_500 doesn't exist, then the how create index function will fail and do nothing.

How to make loop keep going through even if create_index made an error on one of the table in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to not hardcode the number for the loop, but iterate over the existing tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_index() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN select tablename, regexp_replace(tablename, '[^0-9]+','') as idx_nr
            from pg_tables
            where tablename ~ 'abc_id_[0-9]+'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('CREATE INDEX %I ON %I USING btree (key)', 
                   'idx_abc_id_'||r.idx_nr, 
                   r.tablename);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When you use the `format()` function is better to use the proper place holders for identifiers.

If you also want to ignore any error when creating the index on an existing table, you need to catch the exception and ignore it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_index() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r record;
    msg text;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN select tablename, regexp_replace(tablename, '[^0-9]+','') as idx_nr
           from pg_tables
           where tablename ~ 'abc_id_[0-9]+'
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE format('CREATE INDEX %I ON %I USING btree (key)', 
                     'idx_abc_id_'||r.idx_nr, 
                      r.tablename);
    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;      
        RAISE NOTICE 'Could not create index for: %, %', r.idx_nr, msg;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```